# Direction in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there any way that tinyMCE sets the direction according to the language of the text Area?( language is not known to me )

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    directionality: "auto",
});
```

works for me , but in official docs https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-docs/blob/master/plugins/directionality.md it is written that possible values for directionality are only 'ltr' and 'rtl'

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly initialize the language of TinyMCE such that the directionality will be recognized:

```js
tinymce.init({
    ...,
    directionality: 'rtl',
    language: 'ar'  // add this line with correct language code, i. e. "ar"
 });
```

[See also this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-docs/issues/659).

Comment: i do not know the language beforehand, and i want rtl if user types in urdu and ltl if he/she types in english